# source model for attribute set names

Tags: magento-enterprise, source-model

as far as I understand when you have a `<source_model>` in your system.xml, it searches through the specified module for the function of getOptionArray(), right now I need to show all the attribute set names in a multi-select in the system configuration and was wondering why getoptionarray does not exist for the `eav/entity_attribute_set`?  does it exist somewhere else which I am not aware of?

```
<show_attributesetname translate="label">
<label>show_attributesetname</label>
<frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
<source_model>eav/entity_attribute_set?????</source_model>
<sort_order>21</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</show_attributesetname>
```

I was wondering if it exists and I just could not find it. if it doesn't exist then I should go ahead and add a tooptionarray to my module.

wanted to know if it really does not exist?? since doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes we do have it, after Kul answered no and came up with toOptionArray, I searched again this time with toOptionArray and found out, we do have the source model for it in the resurces.

here is the answer:

```
<source_model>Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute_Set_Collection</source_model>
```

I'm not sure if my solution is cool enough since I am using resource in source! would love to hear back if anybody thinks what I did is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

No. As far i know there is not any source model to get attribute set. You can create your own source model and add below code to fetch attribute set.

```
public function toOptionArray()
    {
        if (!count($this->_options)) {
            $entityTypeId           = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getTypeId();
            $attributeSetCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
                    ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityTypeId);

            foreach ($attributeSetCollection as $_attributeSet) {
                $this->_options[] = array(
                    'value' => $_attributeSet->getId(),
                    'label' => $_attributeSet->getAttributeSetName()
                );
            }
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
```

Hope this help!

Comment: shouldn't your function be getOptionArray?

Comment: nevermind seems both works

Comment: you helped me to find my answer, I will upvote and then post the answer, the answer is yes we can do it. I searched for toOptionArray and found it for arrtibutesetnames

Comment: @Nickool Perfect I wasn't 100% sure That's why i Mention as far as i know. Glad to know you found proper solution.